# How to write nested select statement in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

My question is how to write nested select statements using sequelize.js, here's what i need to achieve:

```sql
SELECT * from (SELECT id, time FROM table_name ORDER BY time desc) AS `descTime` GROUP BY `id`;
```

I tried this code

```js
User.findAll({
  attributes: [[Sequelize.literal('(SELECT id, time FROM table_name ORDER BY time desc)'),
        'descTime']],
      group: ['id'],
    });
```

but it didn't work

Comment: For this query, (1) you don't need a nested query, and (2) You are misusing MySQL's [notorious non-standard GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).
 because your `SELECT *` mentions the `time` column which is neither an aggregate function nor mentioned in your GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get what I guess you want with this query. It's a bit simpler than what you have in your question, and its result set is more predictable.

```
 SELECT id, MAX(`time`) `time` FROM table_name GROUP BY id
```